# What's the range of the tablet?

Tags: night-at-the-museum

In *Night at the Museum: Battle of the Smithsonian*, the tablet of Akmenrah that brings the museum to life is taken to the Smithsonian.

In the American Museum of Natural History in New York, the effect of the tablet was confined to the museum, to the confines of the building, although once brought to life, the exhibits could leave the museum.
The Smithsonian consists of several buildings, connected by a number of tunnels and the National Archives underneath. Once the tablet enters one of the buildings, does the *entire* Smithsonian come to life? Does the Smithsonian count as one big museum for the purpose of the tablet's powers?

**What is the range of the effect of the tablet of Akmenrah?**

Note that when Larry arrived, the night guards didn't show signs of the museum having come to life the previous night, while the exhibits from New York *had* come to life in the depot and had phoned Larry.

Comment: The Smithsonian pretends to be several museums but is in fact one large museum, just like the Museum of Natural History and Science Museum in London. The tablet appears to work on 1 x museum.